# cat /dev/null to multiple files to clear existing files like logs

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, tee

A good way to clear logs(syslog has a handle on file) which have frozen my linux server(out of space) I tried `cat /dev/null > fileABC; cat /dev/null/ > fileXYZ`

How can I clear multiple files by cat /dev/null to multiple files in an efficient or single command.

Comment: `cp dev/null/ whatever` does not make sense to me. null is a device file

Comment: Made some edits.. what I meant was to cat it. pl check this for clearing contents of existing file http://goo.gl/UJXEy3

Comment: @Samuel u r right. but how can I do the same for 10-15 files at a time..

Comment: /dev/null is conventionally a destination, not a source.  Are you saying you want to overwrite the file with nothing, setting the length to 0?

Comment: `>fileABC` does the same thing, with no `cat` needed.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy OR printf '' > fileABC as you said in the other comments

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Hard coded solutions**

**`tee`**

Echo nothing and simply send it to multiple files using the `tee` command.

Like this:

```
$ echo -n | tee file1 file2 file3 file4 file5
```

All files in that list will be empty and created if they don't exist.

Applied to your answer this would be:

```
$ cat /dev/null | tee fileABC fileXYZ
```

While `echo -n` is considered better practice than `cat /dev/null`, an even better solution would be to use `printf ''`, as noted by *Charles Duffy*. Resulting in following command:

```
$ printf '' | tee file1 file2 file3
```

**`truncate`**

As answered by *skrilled*, `truncate` is probably the solution you were originally looking for. The command allows arbitrarily many file name arguments to be supplied. You can easily use it as follows:

```
$ truncate --size 0 file1 file2 file3 file4 file5
```

Which allows you to achieve your goal without using any pipe and in a single command, pretty nifty answer supplied here by *skrilled*.

**Structural file names solution**

If all files have a structure on their names (for instance [java](/questions/tagged/java) files) and location you could use the find command. In the following example I will apply the erasure to all `.java` and `.c` source files in the current directory and in all directories inside the current directory.

```
$ find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -name '*.java' -exec truncate --size 0 "{}" \;
```

Explained:

- `find .` execute `find` in current directory `.`
- `-maxdepth 2` recursion level, descend to directories in directory but no further (level 2). Set this to 1 to not descend or `n` to descend `n` times.
- `-type f`  only apply to files, not directories
- `-name '*.java'` only apply to files ending in `.java`
- `-exec truncate --size 0 "{}" \;` truncate each file found (file name is stored in `{}`)

See `man find` for more options and a more detailed explanation. Be sure to check it out because `find` is one of the most powerful tools for automation of file editing.

**List of files in separate file solution**

The easiest thing to do might be to store the files to erase in a file, line by line. If there is no obvious structure with respect to their location and name, that is.

Say the files are stored in a file called `erasure`.

```
$ cat erasure
fileABC
fileXYZ
dir/anotherFile
```

In this example we will erase three files, which are listed above.

```
$ while read file; do > "$file"; done < erasure
```

Explanation:

- `while read file` for each line in the given file, store the line in variable `file`
- `do > "$file"` empty the file and output nothing in it (i.e. erase it)
- `done < erasure` specify the input file using `<` (redirection)

Note: while this method preserves spaces in the path, it fails to handle backslashes and trailing white space, as noted by *Charles Duffy*. One way to fix both issues is to modify the loop as follows:

```
while IFS= read -r file; do > "$file"; done < erasure
```

Yet newlines in file names will still be a problem. The only way around this issue is to separate the file names using null termination (`\0`). The correct loop now becomes:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do > "$file"; done < erasure
```

Comment: Thanks. cat /dev/null | tee fileABC fileXYZ works but I didnt understand echo command and why are we using that here. Second code snippet suffices right? Am I missing something

Comment: They are equivalent, `echo -n` is a zero output, which is considered better practice than `cat /dev/null`. Don't forget to accept if the answer helped and upvote if you deem it a quality answer.

Comment: @ShellFish, I'd argue that `printf ''` is much better practice than `echo -n` -- see the POSIX echo spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html, and note that while `-n` is part of BSD echo, it's not there in the SysV-derived spec.

Comment: ...as for the `while read file` approach, this is quite buggy as-given: Doesn't correctly handle filenames with literal backslashes, for instance (would need `read -r`), doesn't handle filenames whose names end in whitespace (would work with `IFS= read`); doesn't handle filenames containing literal newlines (which can't be fixed while still using line-oriented rather than NUL-delimited input).

Comment: Thank you for your comments, as always, it's great to learn from an experienced guy like you. I will update my post when I get home and will of course credit you. Thanks for the pointers!

Comment: @ShellFish Great solution and thanks for the insight. Appreciate it.

Comment: Wow. Now that's what we call a comprehensive answer. Great stuff.

Comment: "Structural file names solution" doesn't work with multiple files the -o argument `find /root/bc/ -type f -name debug.log -o -name db.log -exec truncate --size 0 "{}" \;` only last file db.lg will be truncated, but if you run this without `-exec` find will display all files. How to solve this?

Comment: found an answer here https://www.tecmint.com/linux-find-command-to-search-multiple-filenames-extensions/

Comment: more abbreviated (be careful): `cat /dev/null | tee file*` instead of `cat /dev/null | tee file1 file2 file3`

Answer (score 5):

Truncate can be used to empty a file as well.

```
truncate --size 0 /path/to/file/here
```

Comment: I dont have truncate installed on my box but sure.. taht will do but can I have multiple files listed next to each other? say: "truncate --size 0 log1 log2 log3?

Comment: `truncate` is indeed the best solution but the main issue is handling several files. While `truncate` indeed supports multiple files, it should be added to the answer to clear that up for the OP. So I'd just append another file name to the command. Great answer though, if my answer ends up being accepted I will include this in the answer if it's okay with you (of course you'll be credited).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it quite nicely with **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
parallel '>' ::: TooLong.log BigBoy.dat NonExistant.file
```